# Array of stdClass objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I need to pull out the [name] information only from this array that includes php stdClass Objects.  How do I do this please?

```
Array ( [VigdiH] => stdClass Object ( [ip] => 555.50.175.142 [name] => Test Name [origin] => www [cycle_day] => 3 [email] => adsf0140@ladf.ca [campaign] => 5555 [created_on] => 2014-03-28 14:22:58 [changed_on] => ))
```

Answer (score 3):

If your array is named `$arr` you could do:

```
foreach($arr as $object) {
    echo $object->name . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get properties from an object using `->`

```
$data = array(/**/);
$data["VigdiH"]->name; // name
```